# Floating image distorting unordered list in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, css-float, html-lists

Code is here: [removed] if you notice the 3 content boxes in the center of the page, all of them have an image floating left and 2 of them have an unordered list as well. In chrome/ff the unordered list properly moves to the right side of the floated image, but in IE9 the image seems to expand the list width pushing the bullets over the the left side of the box. I have tried everything I can think of and haven't had any luck, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE9 doesn't know how to place List Item position corectly, use :

```
li{list-style-position: inside;}
```

on the lists inside the div with the floated images. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Check your html. there are `<p>` tags which aren't closed. i can't live edit your page in ie9 at the moment, but this might be the problem.

Edit:
but it wasnt. It works if you manually set the width of the `<li>` elements, but this would mean to edit the padding of your image (which you do not want, because it will look different in not-ie browsers). 
It actually is correct in "compatibility mode" of ie9..